# Interrupt recursive .AsParallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I'm writing a .NET 4.0 C# software and I need to execute some code in parallel to speed up a job.

I have a `Job` class that may contain multiple `Job` classes as children.
Whenever a `Job` starts running, it calls `Children.AsParallel.ForAll(ch => ch.Run());`

I start the work on a separate thread, but it could happen that I have to terminate it by using `Thread.Abort()` and then `Thread.Join(5000)` to ensure it has terminated.

Anyway it seems that Jobs running under `.AsParallel()` continues to work normally nonetheless...

Here's the code:

```
class Job
{
    public string Name;

    public List<Job> Children = new List<Job>();

    public void Run()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            var msg = "JOB " + Name + " " + tid;

            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }

        Children.AsParallel().ForAll(j => j.Run());
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMultiThread()
{
    var root = new Job();
    root.Name = "A";
    root.Children = new List<Job>()
    {
        new Job() { Name = "B" },
        new Job() { Name = "C" },
    };

    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            root.Run();
        }
        catch(ThreadAbortException tae)
        {

        }
    });
    t.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
    Debug.WriteLine("THREAD.ABORT");
    t.Abort();
    t.Join(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

Here's the output:

```
JOB A 14
JOB A 14
JOB A 14
JOB A 14
JOB A 14
JOB B 9
JOB C 15
JOB B 9
JOB C 15
THREAD.ABORT
JOB B 9
JOB C 15
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Test.dll
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread interrotto.
   in Test.Tests.OtherTests.&amp;lt;&amp;gt;c__DisplayClass14.&amp;lt;TestMultiThread&amp;gt;b__13() in Tests.cs:riga 280
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in Test.dll but was not handled in user code
The thread '<No Name>' (0x14d0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
JOB B 9
JOB C 15
JOB B 9
JOB C 15
The thread '<No Name>' (0x152c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Is there something I miss?

Comment: Use `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel, do not abort a thread!

Comment: `AsParallel` creates other threads. You just kill *the thread that creates other threads*.

Comment: @Eser I had that suspect...

Comment: @TesX in practice all you are doing is aborting one thread, but not the underlying threads created by `AsParallel()` take a look at the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460707(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter mentioned, you can use CancellationTokenSource and cancel the token. What I done here  use the Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested to break all tasks.

Your modified code
:

```
void Main()
{
    TestMultiThread();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Job
{
    public string Name;

    public List<Job> Children = new List<Job>();

    public void Run(CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            int tid = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            var msg = "JOB " + Name + "  " + tid +"  cnt "+  i;

            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            tokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

        Children.AsParallel()
                .ForAll(j => j.Run(tokenSource));
    }
}

public void TestMultiThread()
{
    var root = new Job();
    root.Name = "A";
    root.Children = new List<Job>()
    {
        new Job() { Name = "B" },
        new Job() { Name = "C" },
    };
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var t  =  System.Threading
                    .Tasks
                    .Task
                    .Factory.StartNew(()=> root.Run(cts),cts.Token);

    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7));
    Debug.WriteLine("Task Cancel requested");
    cts.Cancel();
    Debug.WriteLine("Task Canceled");
    try
    {
        t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Linqpad famous Dump method
        ex.Dump();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Thread.Abort use a flag instead so you can control when to quit the job exactly. Have a look at the TPL documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do this without using a flag? Because in practice inside the `Job` I call an external library to do some long calculation and there I can't check the flag...